# Django Model / Form - Fetch existing model and associating with another

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Say I have

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField()
    postal_code = models.CharField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address')
```

How can I have a form input that uses postal_code to fetch a preexisting `Address` and then assign it to a new `Person`?

I think I understand how to do it if I was inserting a new `Address` as well but -- how do I fetch the `Address` before saving `Person`? (Having postal_code validation and all)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want '' around Address in the foreign key.
Is this what you mean?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        address = Address.objects.get(postal_code=form.cleaned_data["postal_code"])
        Person(someStreetVar, address)
        Person.save()
```